# How to convert an arc to parabola?

Tags: geometry, optimization, analytic-geometry

I've got a function that result's in an ascending arc form and with zero results in both ends. The only thing that matters is the maximum of the arc that always will be at the ending point of the arc. **but we do not know the coordinates of the maximum point.**

how can I convert this result to a parabola to help to find the maximum point? It's like having symmetry from the maximum point. like I said other results than maximum doesn't matter so zero parts can be non-zero or vice versa, but the maximum must be stable.

Example for the mentioned arc:

[image]

and the function is :

```
c1 = log2(1 + (sin(p) ^ 2) * 2 * 1000)
c2 = log2(1 + ((cos(p) ^ 2) * 2 * 10) / (1 + (sin(p) ^ 2) * 2 * 10))
if c1<1.5 or c2<1.5:
 c = 0 
else:
 c =(c1 + c2) ^ 3
```

Comment: Can you provide the function ?

Comment: Stated this way, any parabola would go. You should give some additional details.

Comment: c1 = log2(1 + (sin(p) ^ 2) * 2 * 1000)
c2 = log2(1 + ((cos(p) ^ 2) * 2 * 10) / (1 + (sin(p) ^ 2) * 2 * 10))
===>
if c1<1.5 or c2<1.5:
    c = 0
else:
    c =(c1 + c2) ** 3

Comment: How any parabola can provide the exact maximum point?? The objective is to have exact maximum coordinates in a parabola. My question is how can we convert a function of arc to be symmetric without knowing the maximum.

Comment: The maximum can be found exactly with paper and pencil. Why would you need a parabola?

Comment: It's actually a reinforcement learning problem. we need to find the maximum with gradient descent and the best way of finding it is with a convex function. with an arc, accuracy will be lower. so I want to adapt my function to solve better with the gradient descent.

Comment: I can't see any way that the formulas you wrote are related to the graph. The only independent variable in sight is $p$, and the expressions for $c_1$ and $c_2$ are each periodic with period $\pi.$

Comment: As for the "parabola", I don't see any indication that anything you have shown (formulas or graph) has a parabolic shape. As far as I can tell the only way you can get the kind of parabola you want is to find the maximum by other means and then construct a parabola with its vertex at the desired maximum. Obviously the parts of that procedure that involve a parabola are just a waste of time and effort.

Comment: I don't think "gradient descent" can be of any use in this case, because maximum occurs at a point where the function is not differentiable.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca exactly! that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @fardisnadimi But what is the meaning of your question then? Maximum occurs at $c2=1.5$, from that you can find $\sin(p)$, substitute into $c1$ and finally find $c$. What else do you need?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca look, actually we do not have this figure. in an RL learning problem, we have to explore the environment to have a little sight of this figure. and after that gradient descent will be used. as I told you before, my question is not finding the maximum. my question is how to make this function symmetric from the maximum point without knowledge of the maximum point.